# Help in Identifying bicycle frame maker

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I've had this bicycle since 1996. I got it as payment from a client i used to have. I love the frame but i have never known which company manufactured it. I believe it's chromoly it is very well built and has dropped seat stays. it has a serial number on the headset but no other info available for Id purposes.

Thank You.

[image: my old bike]

Comment: Just curious, why is it a screen shot from a gallery if that's your bike?

Comment: I wouldn't call those dropped stays. I'd call those wishbone stays. They're distinctive in the way they run alongside the "wish tube" and are capped off. Usually they curve into the wish tube or are mated to it via something like a fork crown. The fact that the serial number is stamped in the head tube suggests this was a factory-built bike, not from a small framebuilder.

Comment: Hey Molot, its from a gallery hosted on my website. The picture was the last upgrade i gave to my bike. Before covid pandemic i was about to launch a small bicycle customization bussiness. http://www.ojodecain.com/mtmok/

Comment: Adam Rice, thnx for the input and clarification. I will try to find a a manufacturer,

Comment: I think they attach enough below the top tube that I would call this a dropped stay bike. Being dropped and wishbone and having that unusual design on the wishbone means that the frame is fairly distinctive, so you’ll know for sure when you have a match